# How to detect mouse change of direction?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to detect when the user changes direction with a mouse drag. Think detecting a "shake". Detecting a left <-> right "shake" is trivial, but that isn't enough for what I need. Adding in the up <-> down detection is also trivial, its the diagonal shakes that are messing me up.

So, I drew this out on a paper and I'm thinking there are 8 directions: N,S,W,E,NW,NE,SW,SE.

On the non-diagonals, to me, a change in direction is only 3 of the other directions, but on the diagonals, its 5.

For example, on E, a change of direction would only be NW, W and SW, but on NE, it would be NW, W, SW, S, SE. Unless my thinking is off... but to me E -> S is not a change in direction.

Another complication is that diagonal moves don't always come in one event (even with a threshold).

Anybody have any insight on this?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Sure you could detect the mouse acceleration, but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Just what I said... detect a mouse "shake" event. If the user changes mouse direction x times in t time, its considered a "shake".

Comment: I suggest you calculate and average out the `jerk` over a certain period of time. If that average is over a certain threshold you trigger the event. However I am concerned about the UX perspective.